# JavaScript: Is it possible to update the value of an array item with forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I want to cycle through an array of numbers and if any of those numbers are single digit add a `0` before it, eg `1` becomes `01`.

I could do this with a `for` loop but was wondering if I could use `forEach` as it seems neater.

Would anyone know if this can be done?

My code so far:

```
  numArr.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item < 10) {
      item = '0' + item; // How do I update this value in array?
    }
  });
```

Comment: `map` function is more appropriate for this.

Comment: @randomSoul I did look into map but was not sure how to make it work in this case

Comment: See [`String#padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass *index* as the second parameter to event handler function and use that *index* to modify the item in array:

```
numArr.forEach(function(item, i) {
  if (item < 10) {
    numArr[i] = '0' + item; // How do I update this value in array?
  }
});
```

You can also use `map()`:

```
numArr = numArr.map(function(item, i) =>  {
  if (item < 10) {
    item = '0' + item; // How do I update this value in array?
  }
  return item;
});
```

Comment: Also, the array you're working on is the third argument, so if you use that, you can have the logic completely separate from what you are iterating on.

Comment: @Mamun 0+item will add the two numbers

Comment: @MonicaAcha it's the code OP is already using. Sure, it doesn't make much sense as it's a no-op but still.

Comment: `0 + item` converts the value to number

Comment: Yes @MonicaAcha and Manum I missed that when writing. The '0' is meant to be a string. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could map the array with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and convert the value to string and pad with a wanted length and value.

```js
var numArr = [1, 2, 3, 10],
    zeroes = numArr.map(v => v.toString().padStart(2, '0'));

console.log(zeroes);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify your array in place, then [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is the way to go and you'll have to use the index for that, which is the second argument of your callback.

However, if you want to generate a new array, I suggest using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which returns a new item for each iteration:

```js
const numArr = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 100, 3.14];

const prefix = x => {
  const s = `0${x.toString().replace('-', '')}`;
  return s.split('.')[0].length >= 3 ? `${x}` : `${x < 0 ? '-' : ''}${s}`;
}

const result = numArr.map(prefix);

numArr.forEach((x, i) => numArr[i] = prefix(x));

console.log(result);
console.log(numArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example),

```js
var numArr = [1, 2, 3,10,11];
numArr = numArr.map(function(item) {
   if (item < 10) {
      return item = '0' + item;;
    }
  return item.toString() ;
});
console.log(numArr);
```

One more oprtion is to use `forEach` with two parameters(second parameter will be index),

```js
var numArr = [1, 2, 3,10,11];
numArr.forEach(function(item,index) {
   if (item < 10) {
      numArr[index] = '0' + item;
    }
  
});

console.log(numArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var cont = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12];
var result = cont.map((o)=>{ return o.toString().padStart('2', 0);});

console.log(result);
```